Calculate quickly $\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}\ dx$ with $a,b>0$.
We have $$\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}\ dx$$ with $a,b\in \Bbb R $ and $>0$. To solve this integral I can use a hyperbolic substitution as $$x = \color{red}{ \frac{a}{b}\ \sinh u} $$ Consequently I will have $$dx = \frac{a}{b} \cosh u \ du,$$
Hence
$$\int \sqrt{a^2 + b^2x^2} \ dx = \int \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 \left( \frac ab \sinh u \right)^2}\cdot \frac{a}{b}\ \cosh u \ du $$
Simplify the expression inside the square root:
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 \left( \frac{a}{b} \sinh u \right)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + a^2 \sinh^2 u} = \sqrt{a^2 (1 + \sinh^2 u)} = a \sqrt{1 + \sinh^2 u}$$
Using the hyperbolic identity $ \cosh^2 u - \sinh^2 u = 1 $, we have:
$$\sqrt{1 + \sinh^2 u} = \cosh u $$
Now, the integral becomes:
$$\int a \cosh u \cdot \frac{a}{b} \cosh u\ du  
= \frac{a^2}{b} \int \cosh^2 u\ du $$
To integrate $\cosh^2 u$, we use the identity:
$$\cosh^2 u = \frac{1 + \cosh(2u)}{2}$$
So the integral becomes:
$$\frac{a^2}{b} \int \frac{1 + \cosh(2u)}{2}\ du = \frac{a^2}{b} \left( \frac{1}{2} \int 1\ du + \frac{1}{2} \int \cosh(2u)\ du \right) $$
Being
$$\int 1\ du = u $$
$$\int \cosh(2u)\ du = \frac{1}{2} \sinh(2u) $$
So the integral is:
$$ \frac{a^2}{b} \left( \frac{u}{2} + \frac{\sinh(2u)}{4} \right) + k $$
Considerating $$u = \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) $$ we have:
$$x = \frac{a}{b} \sinh u \implies u = \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) $$
Using the identity $$\sinh(2u) = 2 \sinh u \cosh u, $$
$$\sinh(2u) = 2 \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right)^2} = \frac{2bx}{a} \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + b^2 x^2}{a^2}} = \frac{2bx}{a^2} \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 x^2} $$
So the final result is:
$$\frac{a^2}{b} \left( \frac{1}{2} \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) + \frac{bx \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 x^2}}{2a^2} \right) + k = $$$$\frac{a^2}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) + \frac{a^2}{b} \cdot \frac{bx \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 x^2}}{2a^2} + k = \frac{a^2}{2b} \sinh^{-1} \left( \frac{bx}{a} \right) + \frac{x \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 x^2}}{2} + k $$
Integrating for parts the way is more short or wtih another way?

The correct substitution is $x = \frac{a}{b}  \sinh u,$   after which $a^2 + b^2 x^2$ is something nice and $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 x^2}$   is nice

@ТymaGaidash Actually I not understood the negative vote. I know how to solve the integral. After can you please a short answer. Actually I have not understood your steps.

@WillJagy Is not possible to use my substitution?

No, your version of the substitution makes things worse

@Sebastiano Why did you not write $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 \left( \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}} \sinh u \right)^2}$? Your substitution would be for $\int \sqrt{a+bx^2}dx$, but Will’s should be for $\int\sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}dx$. Also, I did not downvote

@ТymaGaidash Done!

@WillJagy Done!

Your integral in the edit still has $\sqrt\frac ab$ and $dx$ is wrong. You can pretty easily turn the integral to be in terms of $\int\cosh^2(u)du$ and use trigonometric identities or expand $\cosh(u)$ in terms of $\exp(u)$.

I edited in two displayed lines with question marks at the ends. Please edit in the correct expressions instead of the question marks. We need you to see why the revised substitution works out.

list of identities at https://trigidentities.info/hyperbolic-trig-identities/#google_vignette

@WillJagy ok. thank you very much. Do i must add the steps how to solve the integral?

I was out getting groceries for several minutes. Thank you for typing in the intermediate steps and the final antiderivative.

@WillJagy But is there not a short way :-(? I have seen the Italy team soccer and I have done the steps in the meanwhile.

Integration by parts
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2} d x \\
& =x \sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}-\int x \cdot \frac{2 b^2 x}{2 \sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}} d x \\
& =x \sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}-\int \frac{a^2+b^2 x^2-a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}} d x \\
& =x \sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}-I+a^2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}} d x \\
I & =\frac{1}{2}\left(x \sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}+a^2 \int \frac{1}{a \cosh \theta}\cdot \frac{a}{b} \cosh \theta d x\right),\quad \textrm{  where }b x=a \sinh \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}+\frac{a^2}{b} \theta\right)+C \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[x \sqrt{a^2+b^2x^2}+\frac{a^2}{b} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{b x}{a}\right)\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you very much for your answer. Upvoted you. But is $x \sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}$ in the third step and not $x \sqrt{a^2+b^2 }$?

Thank you for pointing out typo.

Its a standard problem arising in transforming elliptic integrals.
With $$\sqrt{k^2 x^2+1}\  dx \quad \text{/.}\quad  \left\{k^2 x^2\to \sinh ^2(u),\quad \sqrt{1+k^2 x^2}\to \frac{\cosh (v)}{k},\quad dx\to \frac{dv \cosh (v)}{k}\right\}=\frac{1}{k^2} \  \cosh ^2(v) \ dv $$
The square of trigonometrics can be integrated by parts, replicating the original
$$\int \cosh^2 x dx = \sinh x \cosh x - \int \sinh^2 x dx = \sinh x \cosh x - \int (\cosh^2 x -1) dx$$
The result is
$$\frac{1}{2} x \  \sqrt{k^2 x^2+1}-\frac{1}{2 k}\ \log \left(\sqrt{k^2 x^2+1}-k x\right) $$

Thank you very much for your answer. Upvoted you.
